# How to save a binary file to file system

Tags: java, file, binary

I receive a file from frontEnd (browser). this file is converted to binary then sent to the backend (Java). For example, a file converted to this binary and then sent to backend :

> e1xydGYxXGFuc2kNCkxvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0DQpccGFyIH0=

How can I save this binary as a file on the fileSystem with the java language?

Comment: This is not binary. It is base64-encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a format called 'base64'. You can decode base64, and write it to a file:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(
        "e1xydGYxXGFuc2kNCkxvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0DQpccGFyIH0=");

        Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get("/path/to/some/file");
        Files.write(path, data);
    }
}
```